# How to group data by this week and last week records using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an array of objects that have dates properties in it. I wanted to group it by this week's record and last week's record. What's the best way of achieving this using javascript and moment.js. Below is the structure of the dataset.

```
const obj = [{
   first_name: "Peter",
   last_name: "Hansen",
   date: "2018-01-01"
},
{  first_name: "Jonas",
   last_name:"Da Vinci",
   date: "2018-01-02"
},
{  first_name: "Ohmel",
   last_name: "Reynolds",
   date: "2018-01-03"
},
{  first_name: "Raisa",
   last_name: "Johnson",
   date: "2017-12-25"

},
{
   first_name: "Karen",
   last_name: "Anderson",
   date: "2017-12-26"
},
{
   first_name: "Kristina",
   last_name: "Alvaro",
   date: "2017-12-27"
}]
```

Expected Output:

This Week

- Peter Hansen
- Jonas Da Vinci
- Ohmel Reynolds

Last Week

- Raisa Johnson
- Karen Anderson
- Kristina Anderson

Answer (score 2):

You can group your array based on the week using `array#reduce`.

```js
const arr = [{ first_name: "Peter", last_name: "Hansen", date: "2018-01-01" }, { first_name: "Jonas", last_name:"Da Vinci", date: "2018-01-02" }, { first_name: "Ohmel", last_name: "Reynolds", date: "2018-01-03" }, { first_name: "Raisa", last_name: "Johnson", date: "2017-12-25"}, { first_name: "Karen", last_name: "Anderson", date: "2017-12-26" }, { first_name: "Kristina", last_name: "Alvaro", date: "2017-12-27" }];
var sortedByWeek = arr.reduce((res, {date, first_name, last_name}) => {
  var startOfWeek = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').startOf('week').add(1,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  res[startOfWeek] = res[startOfWeek] || [];
  res[startOfWeek].push(first_name + ' ' + last_name);
  return res;
},{});

console.log(sortedByWeek);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```